# gcloud app engine flexible - removing header from microservice python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud

I've created a microservice (python) serving web requests made from a JavaScript served by an external website. I need the attribute `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the header or else the browser won't take the input from my microservice.

My issue is that gcloud flexible app engine seems to remove my header. I do get the header when I run the python from a vm (in gcloud), but I don't get it when I run it as an "app" in gcloud.

I tried modifying `app.yaml` to add `access-control-allow-origin : *`, but you can't do this when using a script handler.

Part of my python where I inject the header:

```
response_headers = [('Content-type','json/application; charset=utf-8'),('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')]
start_response(status,response_headers)
```

My `app.yaml`:

```
entrypoint: python autocomp.py  
env: flex  
runtime: python  

handlers:  
- url: /.*  
    script: autocomp.py
```

Comment: I don't think we're doing anything to remove that header on responses *scratches head*.  Just FYI - the handlers: section in app.yaml does absolutely nothing in `env:flex` :)

Comment: thanks for responding. If you are interested, I can give you the python file and you can try on your end.  I'm checking the header in my browser, and I do get the access-control when I run the python from a vm (in gcloud), but i dont get it when i run the very same python in an appengine.

Comment: I get the following in chrome console. If you look below, there is a redirect happening before I reach my microservice. I guess whatever haproxy/lb runs in front of my container is changing the header.  I'll try to do a tcpdump in my appengine later today.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://sadfsadf.appspot.com/?search=p. Redirect from 'https://asdfsadf.appspot.com/?search=p' to 'https://asdfsadf.appspot-preview.com/?search=p' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://12.12.12.12' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

This was a temporary problem due to a redirect.  We were redirecting all appspot.com domain traffic for flex users to appspot-preview.com while working out some issues with our request path.  The issue has been fixed, and you shouldn't be seeing any redirects.  Hope this helps!